# what file types are supported in signtool?

Tags: digital-signature, signtool

What are the supported file types in windows signtool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe ?

Can I sign any file types with signtool?
I couldn't find the info on the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe.

please advise.
thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box signtool can sign the following formats:

- PE files (.exe, .dll, .sys, .efi, .scr)
- Microsoft installers (.msi)
- APPX/MSIX packages (.appx, .appxbundle, .msix, .msixbundle)
- Catalog files (.cat)
- Cabinet files (.cab)
- Scripts (.js, .vbs, .wsf, .ps1)
- Silverlight applications (.xap)

More formats can be supported by installing a Subject Interface Package library (SIP):

- Microsoft Office files (.xls, .doc, etc) with the [Office SIP](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56617)
- Microsoft Dynamics 365 extensions (.navx, .app) by installing Microsoft Dynamics NAV
- OpenType fonts with the [Font signing tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/tools/signing-tool/)
- PNG files with [PNGSIP](https://github.com/vcsjones/PngSip)